How to Implement a Transformation Layer for AWS Messaging Framework in .NET?
I'm working with the AWS Messaging Framework in a .NET application, which requires messages to adhere to the CloudEvents standards. I need to transform a custom message format into a format compatible with the CloudEvents specification before the framework can process it, without modifying the original items in the queue.
My original message structure looks like this:
{
  "Type": "Notification",
  "MessageId": "dummy-message-id-1234",
  "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:1234354353412:my-test-topic",
  "Subject": "Event",
  "Message": "{\"events\":[{\"eventId\":\"dummy-event-id-5678\",\"eventTimestamp\":\"2024-10-20T13:43:38Z\",\"eventType\":\"contact_updated\",\"contact\":{\"name\":\"Fake contact Name\",\"systemId\":\"dummy-system-id-9876\"},\"changeOrigin\":\"fake-origin\",\"changeId\":\"dummy-change-id-4321\",\"changedFields\":[\"name\"]}]}",
  "Timestamp": "2024-10-20T13:43:40.140Z",
  "MessageAttributes": {
    "event_type": { "Type": "String", "Value": "contact_updated" }
  }
}

I want to create a transformation layer that adapts the incoming message format so that the AWS Messaging Framework can properly consume them, while keeping the original message intact in the queue.
My Questions:

Is it possible to implement this transformation using the AWS Messaging Framework?
Can someone provide an example of how to implement a message processor that adapts the incoming message format for compatibility with CloudEvents?

